# How can I check if the cached image has same width & height as url image?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, caching

I am writing a script where I am just resizing images from the requested image url and caching them. I am also giving width & height as optional params for the request. I am caching the images by their filenames & I want to cover one use case when user requests the same image with different width or height.

Since I am using Codeigniter's image resizing library, the filenames are appended with _thumb. That's how I am storing the images.

What should I do in that case? One solution would be to check the `md5` hash of the resized image and cached image.

Here's what I am thinking to do:

```
            $ch = curl_init($url); //initialize cURL

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
            $dataToWrite = curl_exec($ch); //Execute the given cURL session. 

            curl_close ($ch); //close the given cURL session
            $fp = fopen($dirPath.$filename,'w');
            fwrite($fp, $dataToWrite); 
            fclose($fp);
```

Finally,

```
           if (md5_file($dirPath.$filename) == md5_file($dirPath.$resizedImage){
                serveimagefromcache() & deletethedownloadedfile();
           } else {
               resizetheimage() && serveit(); 
           }
```

I am concerned about the performance as well, I would appreciate any other suggestions.

Comment: A primitive but very effective solution is to change the naming scheme such that it contains the resolution. Something like `mypic0001_1600_1200.jpg`. This is extremely efficient, since you do not have to open the file to get the information. And you can `glob` a cache folders content in the file system by that naming pattern.

Comment: Would it have any performance issues?

Comment: It certainly is much faster than any other strategy like check sum calculation or actually reading the image dimensions from the file. That is what I mean by "primitive but extremely efficient".

Comment: A variant of this is to have separate caching folders for different image dimensions. That way the file name is irrelevant, you just look at the desired cache folder to see if a matching cached image already exists.

Comment: I might end up using the naming convention based solution, that's the one I had in mind until someone told me to look at the hash method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though @arkascha's suggestion was quite good but saving the file as filename hash is much more better.

With this,

```
$ext   = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);    
$filehash = sha1($filename.$width.$height);
$filename = $filehash.".".$ext
```

you can prevent the issue that I was having.